# how to check calibration of a single camera?

Tags: ros, calibration, monocular-camera, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

What's the best way to check the calibration of a single camera? Is there a way to load the calibration into the `camera_calibration` package and check it using any checkerboard? (I do not have the original apparatus used to calibrate the camera)

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276488/how-to-check-calibration-of-a-single-camera?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2017-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answered in #q256427 - though that answer and the wiki page linked there could be unclear.  I haven't tried it yet (I will and update this answer), but my understanding is that [cameracheck.py](https://github.com/strawlab/image_pipeline/blob/master/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracheck.py) looks at a live rectified image of a checkerboard and analyzes it for distortion.  It analyzes square intersections that ought to be in a straight line for straightness within the rectified image.  Next it finds the checkerboard rotation and translation from all the intersections, then recomputes where the intersections ought to be given the rotation and translation it just found and compares those to the found intersections.

http://wiki.ros.org/camera_calibration#cameracheck.py is on the same wiki page but could be missed.

The camera has to be running with the calibration applied so that the rectified image is published - which is what the other answer meant when they says the commit button needs to be pressed (they are assuming that cameracheck.py is run immediately after running the calibrator tool).

A different sized chessboard/checkerboard can be used than the one used to calibrate with as long as cameracheck.py gets the correct dimensions of the live checkerboard.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1